# Pretty recursive directory and file print

Tags: linux, find, unzip

I am building a JAVA app that saves the output of bash commands into a list.

```
@root ~/a $ zipinfo -1 data.zip 
a.txt
b.txt
test/
test/c.txt

root@ ~/a $ find .
.
./test
./test/c.txt
./b.txt
./data.zip
./a.txt
```

The idea is to compare files and directories from the zip to what is on the disk and remove any differences from the disk. In this example `test/c.txt` should only be removed.

As you can see the format is different. Which command do I need to have the same style as `zipinfo -1`?

I tried commands like:

```
ls -R

ls -LR | grep "" 

find . -exec ls -dl \{\} \; | awk '{print $9}'
```

Comment: any show of effort on your behalf would also be appreciated. what did you try? what are you struggling with? listing files in a folder? recursion?

Comment: You post no java code, which begs the question "why use java at all?"  You can achieve your goal with bash scripting alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to remove the `.` prefix is to use `sed`. For example:

```sh
find . ! -name . | sed -e 's|^\./||'
```

The `! -name .` removes the `.` entry from the list. The `sed` part removes the `./` from the beginning of each line.

It should give you pretty much the same format as your `zipinfo`, though perhaps not the same order.

Note: the above suggestion is compatible with both Linux and other unix versions such as MacOS X. On Linux specifically you can achieve the same result with:

```sh
find . ! -name . -printf "%P\n"
```

The `-printf` predicate is specific to the Linux findutils, and the `%P` format prints each found file, removing the search directory from its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing might be to ask `zip` itself for the list. Its `-sf` option means to show the files it **would** add if it were going to, without actually creating a zip file. So:

```
$ zip add fake.zip -r -sf  *
    zip warning: name not matched: fake.zip
Would Add/Update:
  a.txt
  b.txt
  test/
  test/c.txt
Total 4 entries (0 bytes)
```

You Java code would then have to skip the extraneous header/footer lines that it also outputs, but the file list itself would be in the same format that you're getting from your other execution of `zip`.